# Shopify: link to xml in a js file

Tags: javascript, xml, shopify

Hi I'm using Shopify and I have a js file that I'm loading into a page. The JS file references an xml file. Both the js and the xml file are in the assets folder.

How do I reference the XML file? Below is what I have tried but it does not work. This is the error I'm getting: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://myurl.myshopify.com/pages/%7B%7B%20%27data.xml%27%20|%20asset_url%20%7D%7D"

```
 $(window).load(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ "data.xml" | asset_url }}',
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parse,
        error: function() {
            alert("Error: Something wrong with XML");
            xmlDoc = undefined;
    }
});
});
```

This is what I normally use when I'm not using Shopify. The XML file is in a folder called "xml". This works

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'xml/data.xml',
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parse,
        error: function() {
            alert("Error: Something wrong with XML");
            xmlDoc = undefined;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing when you use {{ "data.xml" | asset_url }} is utilizing Shopify's [URL filters](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/url-filters). The documentation on asset_url specifically can be found [here](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/url-filters#asset_url). You're essentially telling it to look for data.xml in your assets folder. If data.xml is not in your assets folder, but rather in your theme folder, you'll need to remove that Shopify filter and replace it with a real link, either absolute or relative. I can't see the structure of your theme, so I can't provide a more exact answer than that.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I'm just using the default theme at the moment. Online Store/Themes/ I click on "edit HTML/CSS" and am uploading to the assets folder. I have tried naming my js file "config.liquid.js" as I thought that might be the problem.

Comment: Do you have the actual link to the XML file? Is it inside your actual theme? For example, if you're editing the theme, do you see the XML file in the file tree on the left? Or are you uploading them separately into your assets?

Comment: I'm uploading both the js and xml to the same assets folder. I can see them both in the file tree on the left. I don't know how to get the actual link (hard link) although I would prefer not to do that.

Comment: At the top of the page it says: Themes / launchpad-star

Comment: Untill I have a better understanding of how this works I'm going to upload the xml as a file: Settings/Files/
Maybe this is the correct thing to do?

Comment: Do you need the xml file to have the .xml extension? If not you may want to host your xml file as a page